# What does the function then() mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I’ve been seeing code that looks like:

```
myObj.doSome("task").then(function(env) {
    // logic
});
```

Where does `then()` come from?

Comment: UPDATED: I found out that it has to do with the CommonJS promises API http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2010/01/19/commonjsjsgi-the-emerging-javascript-application-server-platform/

Answer (score 461):

The traditional way to deal with asynchronous calls in JavaScript has been with callbacks.
Say we had to make three calls to the server, one after the other, to set up our
application. With callbacks, the code might look something like the following (assuming
a xhrGET function to make the server call):

```
// Fetch some server configuration
    xhrGET('/api/server-config', function(config) {
        // Fetch the user information, if he's logged in
        xhrGET('/api/' + config.USER_END_POINT, function(user) {
            // Fetch the items for the user
            xhrGET('/api/' + user.id + '/items', function(items) {
                // Actually display the items here
            });
        });
    });
```

In this example, we first fetch the server configuration. Then based on that, we fetch
information about the current user, and then finally get the list of items for the current
user. Each xhrGET call takes a callback function that is executed when the server
responds.

Now of course the more levels of nesting we have, the harder the code is to read, debug,
maintain, upgrade, and basically work with. This is generally known as callback hell.
Also, if we needed to handle errors, we need to possibly pass in another function to each
xhrGET call to tell it what it needs to do in case of an error. If we wanted to have just one
common error handler, that is not possible.

> The Promise API was designed to solve this nesting problem and the
>   problem of error handling.

The Promise API proposes the following:

1. Each asynchronous task will return a `promise` object.
2. Each `promise` object will have a `then` function that can take two arguments, a `success`
   handler and an `error` handler.
3. The success *or* the error handler in the `then` function will be called only *once*, after
   the asynchronous task finishes.
4. The `then` function will also return a `promise`, to allow chaining multiple calls.
5. Each handler (success or error) can return a `value`, which will be passed to the next 
   function as an `argument`, in the chain of `promise`s.
6. If a handler returns a `promise` (makes another asynchronous request), then the next
   handler (success or error) will be called only after that request is finished.

So the previous example code might translate to something like the following, using
promises and the `$http` service(in AngularJs):

```
$http.get('/api/server-config').then(
    function(configResponse) {
        return $http.get('/api/' + configResponse.data.USER_END_POINT);
    }
).then(
    function(userResponse) {
        return $http.get('/api/' + userResponse.data.id + '/items');
    }
).then(
    function(itemResponse) {
        // Display items here
    }, 
    function(error) {
        // Common error handling
    }
);
```

**Propagating Success and Error**

Chaining promises is a very powerful technique that allows us to accomplish a lot of
functionality, like having a service make a server call, do some postprocessing of the
data, and then return the processed data to the controller. But when we work with
`promise` chains, there are a few things we need to keep in mind.

Consider the following hypothetical `promise` chain with three promises, P1, P2, and P3.
Each `promise` has a success handler and an error handler, so S1 and E1 for P1, S2 and
E2 for P2, and S3 and E3 for P3:

```
xhrCall()
  .then(S1, E1) //P1
  .then(S2, E2) //P2
  .then(S3, E3) //P3
```

In the normal flow of things, where there are no errors, the application would flow
through S1, S2, and finally, S3. But in real life, things are never that smooth. P1 might
encounter an error, or P2 might encounter an error, triggering E1 or E2.

Consider the following cases:

• We receive a successful response from the server in P1, but the data returned is not
correct, or there is no data available on the server (think empty array). In such a
case, for the next promise P2, it should trigger the error handler E2.

• We receive an error for promise P2, triggering E2. But inside the handler, we have
data from the cache, ensuring that the application can load as normal. In that case,
we might want to ensure that after E2, S3 is called.

*So each time we write a success or an error handler, we need to make a call—given our
current function, is this promise a success or a failure for the next handler in the promise
chain?*

**If we want to trigger the success handler for the next promise in the chain, we can just
return a value from the success or the error handler**

**If, on the other hand, we want to trigger the error handler for the next promise in the
chain, we can do that using a `deferred` object and calling its `reject()` method**

> Now What is deferred object?
>
> Deferred objects in jQuery represents a unit of work that will be
>   completed later, typically asynchronously. Once the unit of work
>   completes, the `deferred` object can be set to resolved or failed.
>
> A `deferred` object contains a `promise` object. Via the `promise` object
>   you can specify what is to happen when the unit of work completes. You
>   do so by setting callback functions on the `promise` object.

Deferred objects in Jquery : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Deferred objects in AngularJs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Very well written. This has helped me really nail down promises.

Comment: Is the error handler, the second parameter, always optional?

Comment: If `then()` takes two arguments, for success and error, where does `catch()` fits?

Answer (score 86):

then() function is related to "Javascript promises" that are used in some libraries or frameworks like jQuery or AngularJS.

A promise is a pattern for handling asynchronous operations. The promise allows you to call a method called "then" that lets you specify the function(s) to use as the callbacks.

For more information see: http://wildermuth.com/2013/8/3/JavaScript_Promises

And for Angular promises: http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/09/09/using-angularjs-promises/

Comment: so it's like a callback that executes when task is done? How is it different

Comment: the [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) in the other comment says: `A promise can only succeed or fail once`, and `If a promise has succeeded or failed and you later add a success/failure callback, the correct callback will be called`

Comment: Also, the [Promise nuggets](http://spion.github.io/promise-nuggets/) explains how to use `promise` and what would be done with `callback`

Comment: On the first page, there are chunks of code missing (big white blanks). Most of the people will think of inspecting element and find the fiddle's URLs underneath. This message is for the rest - fiddles still work ;)

Comment: @MuhammadUmer : read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31453579/1350476 (answer by Sid)

Answer (score 43):

**As of ECMAScript6**

The `.then()` method has been included with pure JavaScript with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises).

From the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

> The then() method returns a Promise. It takes two arguments: callback
> functions for the success and failure cases of the Promise.

The Promise object, in turn, is defined as

> The Promise object is used for deferred and asynchronous
> computations. A Promise represents an operation that hasn't completed
> yet, but is expected in the future.

That is, the `Promise` acts as a placeholder for a value that is not yet computed, but shall be resolved in the future. And the `.then()` function is used to associate the functions to be invoked on the Promise when it is resolved - either as a success or a failure.

**Before ECMAScript6**

To my knowledge, there isn't a built-in `then()` method in `javascript` (at the time of this writing).

It appears that whatever it is that `doSome("task")` is returning has a method called `then`.

If you log the return result of `doSome()` to the console, you should be able to see the properties of what was returned.

```
console.log( myObj.doSome("task") ); // Expand the returned object in the
                                     //   console to see its properties.
```

Comment: There wasn't a built-in `.then` back then, but native promises are coming now in ES6: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Answer (score 26):

Here is a thing I made for myself to clear out how things work. I guess others too can find this concrete example useful:

```js
doit().then(function() { log('Now finally done!') });
log('---- But notice where this ends up!');

// For pedagogical reasons I originally wrote the following doit()-function so that 
// it was clear that it is a promise. That way wasn't really a normal way to do 
// it though, and therefore Slikts edited my answer. I therefore now want to remind 
// you here that the return value of the following function is a promise, because 
// it is an async function (every async function returns a promise). 
async function doit() {
  log('Calling someTimeConsumingThing');
  await someTimeConsumingThing();
  log('Ready with someTimeConsumingThing');
}

function someTimeConsumingThing() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })
}

function log(txt) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML += txt + '<br>'
}
```

```html
<div id='msg'></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

### Here is a small [JS_Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/SPiara/ub74vu91/)

**then** is a method callback stack which is available after a promise is resolved it is part of library like jQuery but now it is available in native JavaScript and below is the detail explanation how it works

**You can do a Promise in native JavaScript : just like there are promises in jQuery, Every promise can be stacked and then can be called with Resolve and Reject callbacks, This is how you can chain asynchronous calls.**

I forked and Edited from MSDN Docs on Battery charging status..

What this does is try to find out if user laptop or device is charging battery. then is called and you can do your work post success.

```
navigator
    .getBattery()
    .then(function(battery) {
       var charging = battery.charging;
       alert(charging);
    })
    .then(function(){alert("YeoMan : SINGH is King !!");});
```

#### Another es6 Example

```
function fetchAsync (url, timeout, onData, onError) {
    …
}
let fetchPromised = (url, timeout) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetchAsync(url, timeout, resolve, reject)
    })
}
Promise.all([
    fetchPromised("http://backend/foo.txt", 500),
    fetchPromised("http://backend/bar.txt", 500),
    fetchPromised("http://backend/baz.txt", 500)
]).then((data) => {
    let [ foo, bar, baz ] = data
    console.log(`success: foo=${foo} bar=${bar} baz=${baz}`)
}, (err) => {
    console.log(`error: ${err}`)
})
```

> Definition :: **then is a method used to solve Asynchronous callbacks**
>
> this is introduced in **ES6**
>
> Please find the proper documentation here [Es6 Promises](http://es6-features.org/#PromiseUsage)

Comment: Your answer does not actually answer the question. It only provides an example of the API usage without explaining where `then` comes from and how it works. You should improve your answer to provide those details.

Comment: @TarandeepSingh - in first then statement where you alert the battery status no promise object is returned. Then what is the use of second then

Comment: @MohitJain It showcase you can do multiple callbacks even if you do not have any new promise. Since, the multiple calls could also be done with Promise.all.

Comment: WTH do you mean by "*method callback stack*"?

Answer (score 7):

### It's about the use of curly braces `{}` in our arrow functions:

---

Those 3 examples are doing the same thing (nothing, but have **valid grammar**, and are a **valid Promise chain!**)

---

```js
new Promise(function(ok) {
   ok( 
      /* myFunc1(param1, param2, ..) */
   )
}).then(function(){
     /* myFunc1 succeed */
     /* Launch something else */
     /* console.log(whateverparam1) */
     /* myFunc2(whateverparam1, otherparam, ..) */
}).then(function(){
     /* myFunc2 succeed */
     /* Launch something else */
     /* myFunc3(whatever38, ..) */
})

console.log("This code has no errors GG!")
```

---

The same logic using arrow functions shorthand without `{}`

```js
new Promise((ok) =>
   ok( 
      /* myFunc1(param1, param2, ..) */
).then(() =>
     0 // HEY DID YOU NOTICE! A number that does nothing,
     // but otherwise the parsing will fail!
     // The code is pretty clean but have a major downside
     // As arrow functions without {} can contains only one declaration
     // console.log("something") will FAIL here
).then(() =>
     "" // HEY DID YOU NOTICE! An empty string that does nothing,
     // but otherwise the parsing will fail!
     // As arrow functions without {} can contains only one declaration
     // We can't add more code here, hence:
     // console.log("something")
     // Will break the whole promise
     // This is likely the error in y(our) code ;)
))

console.log("This code has no errors GG!")
```

---

Arrow function with `{}`

```js
new Promise( (ok) => {
   ok( 
      /* myFunc1(param1, param2, ..) */
   )
}).then( () => {
     /* myFunc1 succeed */
     /* Launch something else */
}).then( () => {
     /* myFunc2 succeed */
     /* Launch something else */
     /* myFunc3(whatever38, ..) */
     console.log("something")
     /* More console logs! */
     console.log("something else")
})

console.log("This code has no errors GG!")
```

Answer (score 7):

`.then` returns a promise in async function.

Good Example would be:

```js
var doSome = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve('I am doing something');
});

doSome.then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
});
```

To add another logic to it, you can also add the `reject('I am the rejected param')` call the function and console.log it.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect doSome returns this, which is myObj, which also has a then method.  Standard method chaining...

if doSome is not returning this, being the object on which doSome was executed, rest assured it is returning some object with a then method...

as @patrick points out, there is no then() for standard js

Comment: *I suspect doSome returns this* - nothing enforces/justifies such suspitions

Answer (score 1):

doSome("task")must be returning a promise object , and that  promise always have a then function .So your code is just like this

```
promise.then(function(env) {
    // logic
});
```

and you know this is just an ordinary call to member function .

Answer (score 0):

In this case `then()` is a class method of the object returned by `doSome()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The ".then()" function is wideley used for promised objects in Asynchoronus programming For Windows 8 Store Apps.
As far as i understood it works some way like a callback.

Find Details in this Documentantion
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700330.aspx

Of Cause it could also be the name for any other defined function.

Answer (score -6):

I am about 8 years late, well...anyways, I don't really know what then() does but maybe MDN might have an answer. Actually, I might actually understand it a little more.

This will show you all the information (hopefully), you need. Unless someone already posted this link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

The format is promise.prototype.then()
The promise and prototype are kind of like variables but not like variables in javascript, I mean like other things go there like navigator.getBattery().then() where this one actually exists but is barely used on the web, this one shows statuses about the battery of the device, more information and more on MDN if you are curious.