# Making HTTPS Request with Node.JS to Firebase

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

i am trying to get all docs in collection in firestore with node.js but i can't get any docs althow there is 
someone know what is the problem in this function:

```
exports.getTasksNew8 = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('users/admin/settings').get().then(querySnapshot=>{
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot=>{
            console.log(documentSnapshot.id)
        })
    }).catch(error=>{
    console.log(error)
    })
    response.send('works ok)
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method is asynchronous and returns a Promise: you should "treat" the result within the `then()` method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then and [What does the function then() mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884281/what-does-the-function-then-mean-in-javascript) and also https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies#toc-promises-are-asynchronous

By doing `response.send('works ok)`outside the `then()` you indicate to the Cloud Function that it can finish before the asynchronous `get()` is done.

Modify your code as follows:

```
exports.getTasksNew8 = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
    admin.firestore().collection('users/admin/settings').get().then(querySnapshot=>{
        querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot=>{
            console.log(documentSnapshot.id)
        })
        response.send('works ok);
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
      //See the following video https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series#learn-javascript-promises-pt1-with-http-triggers-in-cloud-functions
    })

})
```