# requireJS require function has a module name without a definition

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to understand this piece of code

```
    require(['mifosXComponents'], function (componentsInit) {
        componentsInit().then(function(){
            require(['test/testInitializer'], function (testMode) {
                if (!testMode) {
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['MifosX_Application']);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The code is at [mifosX client code](https://github.com/openMF/community-app/blob/develop/app/scripts/loader.js#L128). I believe this is the entry point of the mifosX web client software. I am really confused by the `require` syntax here. All the online sample code I have seen is like `require(["a", "b"], function (a, b){});`. In the other words, the parameter list inside the `function()` are all listed inside the dependence `[]` right before it. However the code I pasted above has `componentsInit` inside the `function()`. And I could not find any place in the source code tree that `componentsInit` gets defined.....

What I am trying here is to understand the code logic flow of mifosX. I am new to Javascript and RequireJS. Please help me understand this if you know what's going on here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's defined on line 1 of your code: `function (componentsInit)` is where it is defined.  The required package/library/whatever returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have another question how to understand the `then()` in `componentsInit().then(function()`? `componentsInit()` is just defined, where the member `then()` comes from? Or is it actually defined at line 2?

Comment: Click the link I gave, it's all explained there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code with some comments which will clarify:

```js
// in the first line you are requiring a module with id `mifosXComponents`
// which then is passed to the callback as `componentsInit`
require(['mifosXComponents'], function (componentsInit) {
    // seems that `componentsInit` is a function which returns a Promise object,
    // so your are passing a callback to it to execute it after its fulfilment 
    componentsInit().then(function(){
        // when the promise is fulfilled, you are requiring another module
        // with id `test/testInitializer` which is passed to callback as `testMode`
        require(['test/testInitializer'], function (testMode) {
            // next lines are pretty simple to understand :)
            if (!testMode) {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['MifosX_Application']);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

About Promise you can read here: [What does the function then() mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884281/what-does-the-function-then-mean-in-javascript)