# Trouble understanding the requireJS require() function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm new to Javascript and I'm having troubles understanding the following piece of code. I have read this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60669635/9867856) which suggests that `mifosXComponents.js` and `mifosXStyles.js` are being passed as arguments into the function `function(componentsInit){...}`, but isn't `componentsInit` a single function that returns a promise? How come two `.js` files are converted into a function? I'm confused.

```
require(['mifosXComponents.js', 'mifosXStyles.js'], function (componentsInit) {
        componentsInit().then(function(){
            require(['test/testInitializer'], function (testMode) {
                if (!testMode) {
                    angular.bootstrap(document, ['MifosX_Application']);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require two modules (as per example) then RequireJS will:

- load them async;
- load their dependencies;
- inject the modules to you callback, each as separate argument.

So you have a mistake in your code, your callback will receive actually two arguments, so you need to have two parameters:

```js
// require two modules async,
// when they are loaded,
// they are injected to your callback
require(['mifosXComponents.js', 'mifosXStyles.js'], function (mifosXComponents, mifosXStyles) {
    // now you can use both modules,
    // seems that first one is a function which returns promise,
    // but I have no idea what is the second one :)
    mifosXComponents().then(function(){
        require(['test/testInitializer'], function (testMode) {
            if (!testMode) {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['MifosX_Application']);
            }
        });
    });
});
```