# "Sending request" loading on Get request on Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postman, joi

My `/chat` route works well through `Post` method with validation with `Joi schema` but when I send request through `Get` method, it show `Sending Request` and continue loading...
My index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const chat = require('./db/ChatModel');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
    chat.getAllMessages().then( (messages) => {
        res.json(messages);
    });
});

app.post('/chat', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.dody);
    chat.createMessages(req.body).then((message) => {
        res.json(message);
    }).catch( (error) => {
        res.status(500);
        res.json(error);
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8888;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

In `connection.js` I coded this

```
const monk = require('monk');
const connectionString = 'localhost/chatboard';
const db = monk(connectionString);

module.exports = db;
```

And ChatModal.js has the following code

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const db = require('./connection');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(4).max(16).required(),
    subject: Joi.string().required(),
    message:Joi.string().max(300).required(),
    imgUrl: Joi.string().uri({
        scheme: [      // https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md#stringurioptions
          /https?/
        ]
      })
});

const chat = db.get('chat');

function getAllMessages() {
    return chat.find();
};

function createMessages(message) {
    const result = Joi.validate(message, schema);
    if (result.error == null) {
        message.created = new Date();
        return chat.insert(message);
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(result.error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    createMessages,
    getAllMessages
};
```

I can't understand why `getAllMessages()` doesn't work and postman continue loading when `Get` request applied like this http://prntscr.com/s0d9c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ChatModal.js**

```
function getAllMessages() {
 try {
  return chat.find();
 } catch (err) {
return next(err);
```

}

**index.js**

```
app.get('/chat', (req, res, next) => {
 try{
    data = chat.getAllMessages()
 } catch (err) {
    return next(error);
  }
    res.json(data);
```

});

Comment: Yes, @tapu74! this works now `app.get('/chat', (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        messages = chat.getAllMessages()
    } catch (err) {
        return next (err)
    }
        res.json(messages);
});` So `get` will not support `.then()` function, right? Because it works on `app.post` but `app.get` and thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

User try-catch in the ChatModal.js and also index.js then you can understand what is actual error, like bellow:

**ChatModal.js**

```
function getAllMessages() {
  try {
    chat.find();
  } catch (err) {
  return next(err);
}
```

Comment: Yes, now error shows like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at ... index.js:23:26` In `index.js`, I used `.then()` twice on `app.get` and `app.post`. `Post` works well but `Get` doesn't work and error shows as `TypeError` on `.then()`

Comment: `app.get('/chat', (req, res) => {
    chat.getAllMessages().then((messages) => {
        res.json(messages);
    });
});` For this code, error shows `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: Yes, `app.get` works now on postman but now `app.post` is loading that worked before and when loading after submitting `post` request, `undefined` shows on terminal against `console.log(req.body);` on `index.js`

Comment: **index.js** `app.post('/chat', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.dody);
    chat.createMessages(req.body).then((message) => {
        res.json(message);
    }).catch( (error) => {
        res.status(500);
        res.json(error);
    });
});`

Comment: similar to get, you don't need then in the post also.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884281/what-does-the-function-then-mean-in-javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211817/discussion-between-mostafa-bd-and-tapu74).

Answer (score 0):

I think, may be your data, i mean message list data so weight, in this case you get all message,`res.json(messages);` json method have long time to parse messages data